# How to get nodes and edges data in cytoscape.js from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, cytoscape.js

I have a display network using `cytoscape.js`, I want to display details from mysql table about a particular node and edge whenever the node is clicked.
How can I do that?

I have used the following code which uses function `cy.on` ('tap'). How do I send the `var node_id` to any php page which then use this node and retrieve its information from a mysql table to display the information in a particular division. This code is inside a `$.getJSON` function.

```
        cy.on('tap', 'edge',  function(evt){
          var edge = evt.cyTarget;
          alert( 'Selected ' + edge.source() );
        });
        cy.on('tap', 'node',  function(evt){
          var node = evt.cyTarget;
          alert( 'Selected ' + node.id() );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you can just send an HTTP request containing *node_id* to your server.

If you don't know how to do this in javascript, I suggest taking a look at [the MDN page for XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)